# Problema al crear la matriz del juego del 15

Tags: c

Ayuda, tengo el siguiente código hecho en lenguaje C, el cual es para el juego del 15(taken), en el cual se tiene un tablero de 16 espacios en donde uno está vacío y se tienen que acomodar los números del 1 al 15 de manera ordenada, ya que están desordenados, y es de lo cual va el "puzzle". Cuando ingreso el lugar donde quiero que esté el lugar vacío todo funciona de manera correcta, el problema que tengo es cuando quiero crear la matriz ya que al momento de crearla me coloca puros números aleatorios y sin sentido en los espacios, números basura tales como -234552 o 0 o 134234, por decir algunos ejemplos  pero no me coloca los números que quiero en la matriz desde el número 1 hasta el número 15 de manera desordenada, si me muestra y me imprime la matriz con esos números pero no son los que intento poner, ¿podrían ayudarme a solucionarlo?

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int main(){
 int pair[2],i,j,choice=1,temp;
 int mat[4][4];
 har move = 'a';//just declaring
 printf("Enter pair: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&pair[0],&pair[1]);
 printf("Enter matrix, 15 elements: ");
    scanf("%d",&mat[i][j]);
 for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    for(j=0;j<4;j++){
       if(i==pair[0] && j==pair[1]){
       mat[i][j] = -1;
    }else{
       scanf("%d",&mat[i][j]);
     }
    }
 }
 while(move!='x'){
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
       for(j=0;j<4;j++){
          if(mat[i][j]==-1){
             printf("%-4c",' ');
          }else{
             printf("%-4d ",mat[i][j]);
           }
       }
       printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\nEnter move, u for up, d for down, l for left and r for right x to exit: ");
    scanf("%c",&move);
    scanf("%c",&move);
    if(move=='u'){
       if(pair[0]==0){
          printf("\nThis move is not allowed\n");
       }
       else{
          temp = mat[pair[0]-1][pair[1]];
             mat[pair[0]-1][pair[1]] = -1;
             mat[pair[0]][pair[1]] = temp;
             pair[0] = pair[0]-1;
       }
    }
    else if(move=='d'){
    if(pair[0]==3){
       printf("\nThis move is not allowed\n");
    }
    else{
       temp = mat[pair[0]+1][pair[1]];
       mat[pair[0]+1][pair[1]] = -1;
       mat[pair[0]][pair[1]] = temp;
       pair[0] = pair[0]+1;
       }
    }
    else if(move=='l'){
       if(pair[1]==0){
          printf("\nThis move is not allowed\n");
       }
    else{
       temp = mat[pair[0]][pair[1]-1];
          mat[pair[0]][pair[1]-1] = -1;
             mat[pair[0]][pair[1]] = temp;
                pair[1] = pair[1]-1;
    }
    }
    else if(move=='r'){
       if(pair[1]==3){
          printf("\nThis move is not allowed\n");
       }
    else{
       temp = mat[pair[0]][pair[1]+1];
       mat[pair[0]][pair[1]+1] = -1;
       mat[pair[0]][pair[1]] = temp;
       pair[1] = pair[1]+1;
    }
    }
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Esto no te da error? ` har move = 'a';`

Comment: No, de hecho no me marca ningún error ni siquiera un "warning"

Answer (score 0):

TU codigo tenia varios errores que corregi no esta completo pero es para que te des una idea de como debe de ser asi ya esta bien la logica mover hacia arriba y hacia abajo faltaria la de la derecha y la de la izquierda ahi mismo en el codigo te explico lo que cambie en tu codigo
Ahorita por falta de tiempo nada mas puede completarte estas dos la de arriba y abajo pero si me puedes decir si puede meter punteros ya que asi seria mucho mas agil tu programa ademas de reducir la cantidad de codigo

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int pair1,pair2,i,j,choice=1,temp;
int mat[4][4];
char move = 'a';//just declaring
printf("Enter pair number 1: posiciones permitidass [0,1,2,3]");
scanf("%d",&pair1);
printf("Enter pair number 2  posiciones permitidas [0,1,2,3]\n");
scanf("%d",&pair2);
 for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    for(j=0;j<4;j++){
       if(i==pair1 && j==pair2){
            mat[i][j]=-1;
        }else{
            scanf("%d",&mat[i][j]);
     }
    }
 }
 while(move!='x'){
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
       for(j=0;j<4;j++){
          if(mat[i][j]==-1){
             printf("%c",' ');
          }else{
             printf("%d ",mat[i][j]);
           }
       }
       printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\nEnter move, u for up, d for down, l for left and r for right x to exit: ");
    scanf("%c",&move);
    if(move=='u'){
       if(pair1==3){
          printf("\nThis move is not allowed\n");
       }else{

        /*
          Aqui es donde esta el problema ya que deberia de ser asi 
          primero pasas lo que vale mat a temp por ejemplo
          paii1 = 2
          pair2 = 3
          como mat es una matriz de 4 x 4 entonces se veria algo como esto
          mat | 1  2  3  4  |
              | 5  6  7  8  |
              | 9  10 11 12 |
              | 13 14 15 16 |
          Esa seria tu matriz normal de 4 x 4  pero como dices  hay un lugar en la matriz que
          forsozamente requiere de un espacio en blanco entonces sabieno que pai1 vale 2 por decir un valor para 
          pair1  y pair2 vale por ejemplo 3
          tu matriz se veria asi 
           mat| 1  2  3  4  |
              | 5  6  7  8  |
              | 9  10 11    |  <--- ahi es donde estaria tu espacio en blanco
              | 13 14 15 16 |
          Ahora como puede ver tienes que cambiar los valores el numero 8 debe de esta en el lugar del espacio en blanco
          y tu espacio debe de esta en el lugar del numero ocho o al menos eso entendi de tu codigo 
          pero pues oviamente solo puede llegar hasta la primera fila osea el numero 4 
          ya que en caso ocntario te marcaria error el que tienes arriba que dice "THis move is not allowed"
        */
             temp = mat[pair1-1][pair2];  /*aqui tu mat seria esta mat{2][3]  <- vale 3 porque recueta que pair2 vale 3 en este ejemplo
                                                                     ^ 
                                                                     | 
                                                            tiene el valor 2 porque recuerda que pair1 vale 2 en est ejemplo*/

             mat[pair1-1][pair2]=-1;   /* aqui tendrias mat [2-1][3]  que su valor seria el del espacio es decir aqui ya cambiaste el valor 8 por el espacio*/
             mat[pair1][pair2]=temp;   /* y aqui por ultimp  asignas el 8 al espacio que tenias y listo mi hermano asi con los demas simplemente juegas XD */
            
    }
  }
    else if(move=='d'){
    if(pair1==0){
       printf("\nThis move is not allowed\n");
    }
    else{
       temp = mat[pair1][pair2];  /*aqui valdria esto mat[2][3]  entocne stmep valdria = 16*/
       mat[pair1][pair2-1] = temp;  /* aqu seria mat[2][3-1]=  16*/
       mat[pair1][pair2] = -1;  /*aqui seria mat[2][3] = espacio*/
       }
    }
    /*y asi para lo tros dos caso si no puedes me avisas XD  */
    else if(move=='l'){
       if(pair1==0){
          printf("\nThis move is not allowed\n");
       }
    else{
       temp = mat[pair1][pair2-1];
          mat[pair1][pair2-1] = -1;
             mat[pair1][pair2] = temp;
                pair1 = pair2-1;
    }
    }
    else if(move=='r'){
       if(pair1==3){
          printf("\nThis move is not allowed\n");
       }
    else{

       temp = mat[pair1][pair2+1];
       mat[pair1][pair2+1] = -1;
       mat[pair1][pair2] = temp;
    }
    }
    }
    return 0;
 }
```